# Highcharts Orientation

Tags: highcharts

I have been trying for a couple of days to figure out how to get a chart to layout similar to the one at the following link:

```
http://demos.azimuth1.com/smartdata2/
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to get a chart to look like this and perhaps the settings I should be looking at?

lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set

> inverted:true

```
chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                inverted: true,
                type: 'arearange'
            },
```

[Example JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/inverted/)